# When can't we use the article "the"?

Tags: nouns, articles, proper-nouns

There is an exercise about articles. We must put the necessary article in the underlined places, if necessary, and “x” if it is not.

There we went shopping at **the (Correct is: x)** Harrods, visited **the** Tower and enjoyed a sunny afternoon in **the (Correct is: x)** Hyde Park.

I can't understand why we can't put article "the" in the first and in the last places?
Please correct my question if it's necessary.

Comment: Viewing its contents may be helpful: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/definite-article

Comment: Businesses named after people, and names of places, do not take an article. "The Tower" does because its official name is _the Tower of London_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is better to ask when we *do* use it than when we don't, as exceptions are not usually an exhaustive list.

"The" is a *determiner*. You use it when something needs to be determined! When something does not, you don't usually use it, unless the subject *requires an article*.

For example, it is quite common and idiomatic for people to say they are "going to town", or "going into town". Obviously, there are many towns - but when it is tacit that they are going to *their* town, or the nearest town, there is no need to *determine* which town it is with an article. However - if you were talking about your visit to a different area, it would be expected that you would say you visited "*the* town" there - because it is not the town you would normally refer to.

In your example, you refer to "The Tower of London" as "the Tower". As has already been answered, "The Tower of London" is a proper noun that includes the article. However, in abbreviated form "the Tower" needs an article because "tower" alone is not a proper noun. You could say "I visited *a* tower" if there were many towers in London, but there is one very famous tower and so it requires the *definite* article.

"Harrods" is the complete name of the famous store, so no need for an article.

Comment: Why do we say "the universe"? There's only one of them (as far as we know) so it's not like we need to differentiate it from other universes.

Comment: @CJDennis Actually if you look up 'universe' on Wikipedia you will see several uses of "a universe" as it is believed our universe (commonly referred to as *the* universe) is just one of many within a *multiverse*. That's immaterial though - I can't possibly list every context and exception, a point I made at the beginning of my answer. I believe I addressed the OP's question.

Comment: I disagree. Why do we say "The universe is big" and not "Universe is big"? Why does the universe need to be determined when there's only one of it?

Comment: @CJDennis We would say "Universe**s** *are* big", right? And if you say "the" universe, which one is it? Well, it's *our* universe, obviously. I've covered this in my answer.

Comment: @CJDennis I don't see how I can cover every context in my answer, but I did say "usually" - to make you happy I've clarified this by adding the disclaimer "*unless the subject requires an article*", which I thought went without saying, but evidently not.

Comment: Colin Fine has given the only correct answer so far: proper nouns usually don't take articles. Saying "except when they do take an article" is circular logic.

Answer (score 1):

We basically never use *the* with a proper name. For "the Tower" in your text, "the" is part of the name: *The Tower of London*.

The only exception I can think of is when we use it with a defining phrase. to pick out one of several holders of the name: *The John Smith I went to school with*; *The Brian Cox who is an actor*.

Comment: Or for humorous emphasis of some trait, or lack of some trait, *e.g.* [*"The Donald"*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2015/09/01/why-does-everyone-call-donald-trump-the-donald-its-an-interesting-story/), via Trump's Czech ESL wife whose error went viral...

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between British English and American English in at least one phrase involving "the".

Specifically, in British English, the phrase is "in hospital" as in, "She was in hospital last week." In American English, it is always written as "in the hospital."